# DATASTAGE replace values in csv file

Tags: replace, process, datastage

I have a parallel job in DATASTAGE
which load table from CSV file and insert the values to ORACLE DB.
I want to use process that replace values in one of the column.
let's say I have a column call: ID and I want  to change values like "null" or "0" to value: "N/A"
How can I do it?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the few information in your question it seems a pretty normal job with a transformer stage upfront the Oracle target.
In the derivation field you can specify thing like

[NullToValue](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ft.usage.doc/topics/r_deeref_Null_Handling_Functions.html) (this is a DataStage provided function for the one usecase described) so this would look like `NullToValue(<inputcol>, "N/A")`
or something like `IF <inputcol> = "X" THEN "y"`

This should do the job

Comment: You are welcome but please do not forget to mark it as answer (that is how this forum works) - thanks